# How to deal with the discontinuity in the solution of NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

I have a set of differential equations that describe the air temperature dynamics in a heated channel.The problem is that the solution becomes unstable and creates a discontinuity but physically it should not.Also, the point of the discontinuity depends on the length of the solving region (parameter zz). Are there any ideas how to deal with this issue? Tnx!

```
zz = 100; tt = 600; 
equation1 = {Derivative[0, 1][tair][t, z] == 0.7*(-2*tair[t, z] + tbs[t, z] + ti1[t, z]), 
  4500*Derivative[1, 0][ti0][t, z] == -0.18*(-20 + ti0[t, z]) + 0.18*(-ti0[t, z] + ti1[t, z]), 
  4500*(Derivative[1, 0][ti0][t, z] + Derivative[1, 0][ti1][t, z]) == -0.18*(-20 + ti0[t, z]) + 
    4.94*(0. + tbs[t, z] - ti1[t, z]) - 3*(-tair[t, z] + ti1[t, z]), 
  1033*Derivative[1, 0][tbs][t, z] == -3*(-tair[t, z] + tbs[t, z]) + 
    544*(-tbs[t, z] + tc[t, z]) - 4.94*(tbs[t, z] - ti1[t, z]), 
  1323*Derivative[1, 0][tc][t, z] == 375 - 62.5*(0.998 - 0.00433*(-25 + tc[t, z])) - 
    544*(-tbs[t, z] + tc[t, z]) + 311*(-tc[t, z] + tgl[t, z]), 
  6526*Derivative[1, 0][tgl][t, z] == 250 - 11*(-3.9 + tgl[t, z]) - 1.15*(273.2 + tgl[t, z]) - 
    311*(-tc[t, z] + tgl[t, z]), 
  ti0[0, z] == 17.7, ti1[0, z] == 15.5, tbs[0, z] == 15.5, 
    tair[t, 0] == 3.93, tc[0, z] == 15.5, tgl[0, z] == 15.5}; 
ss = NDSolve[ equation1, {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, {z, 0, zz},  {t, 0, tt},
  Method -> "Adams"]; 
Plot3D[tair[t, z] /. ss, {t, 0, tt}, {z, 0, zz}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"sec", "m", "C"}, PlotLegends -> "Tair"] 
Plot[tair[t, z] /. ss /. t -> tt, {z, 0, zz}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> "Tair"]
```

[image: 3d plot]

[image: 2d plot]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: If you post the `InputForm` of your code, it will be readable on the site.  As it is, I think many will be discouraged from investigating your problem.

Comment: ok tnx. I see someone has changed it already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Substantially Revised Solution**

It is convenient to begin with a modestly simplified version of the equations, named `eq` rather than `equation1` for brevity:

```
eq[[3]] = Simplify[eq[[3, 1]] - eq[[2, 1]]] == eq[[3, 2]] - eq[[2, 2]];
eq = (#[[1]] == Simplify[#[[2]]] // Chop) & /@ eq;
eq = (# /. Equal[c_ z_, r_] :> Equal[z, Simplify[r/c]]) & /@ eq
```

yielding

```
{Derivative[0, 1][tair][t, z] == 0.7*(-2*tair[t, z] + tbs[t, z] + ti1[t, z]), 
 Derivative[1, 0][ti0][t, z] == 0.0008 - 0.00008*ti0[t, z] + 0.00004*ti1[t, z], 
 Derivative[1, 0][ti1][t, z] == 0.0006666666666666666*(tair[t, z] + 
   1.6466666666666667*tbs[t, z] + 0.06*ti0[t, z] - 2.706666666666667*ti1[t, z]), 
 Derivative[1, 0][tbs][t, z] == 0.002904162633107454*(tair[t, z] - 
   183.98000000000002*tbs[t, z] + 181.33333333333334*tc[t, z] + 
   1.6466666666666667*ti1[t, z]), 
 Derivative[1, 0][tc][t, z] == 0.23118622448979595 + 0.41118669690098264*tbs[t, z] - 
   0.6460539493575208*tc[t, z] + 0.23507180650037793*tgl[t, z], 
 Derivative[1, 0][tgl][t, z] == -0.003260802942077838 + 0.047655531719276736*tc[t, z] - 
   0.049517315353968736*tgl[t, z], 
 ti0[0, z] == 17.7, ti1[0, z] == 15.5, tbs[0, z] == 15.5, 
 tair[t, 0] == 3.93, tc[0, z] == 15.5, tgl[0, z] == 15.5}
```

Insight can be obtained by solving the corresponding 1-D problems, obtained by dropping derivatives in the other dimension.  For 1-D in `z`,

```
eqz = Delete[eq, Delete[Table[{-i}, {i, 6}], -4]] /. {Derivative[1, 0][v_][t, z] :> 0, 
Derivative[0, 1][v_][t, z] :> Derivative[1][v][z]} /. v_[t, v1_] :> v[v1];
zz = 10; ssz = NDSolve[eqz, {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, {z, 0, zz}];
Plot[Evaluate[{ti0[z], ti1[z], tbs[z], tair[z], tc[z], tgl[z]} /. ssz], {z, 0, zz},
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[ {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, Scaled[{.9, .4}]]]
```

[image]

Absence of the cusp visible in the Question's plots supports the OP's statement that the cusp is spurious.  It also is worth noting that the variables increase with a scale length of about `4` toward a constant value, which is why the small integration limit `zz = 10` is chosen.

The corresponding 1-D in `t` curves are

```
eqt = Delete[eq, -3] /. {Derivative[0, 1][v_][t, z] :> 0, 
  Derivative[1, 0][v_][t, z] :> Derivative[1][v][t]} /. v_[v1_, z] :> v[v1];
tt = 600; sst = NDSolve[eqt, {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, {t, 0, tt}];
Plot[Evaluate[{ti0[t], ti1[t], tbs[t], tair[t], tc[t], tgl[t]} /. sst], {t, 0, tt}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[ {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, Scaled[{.9, .4}]]]
```

[image]

These solutions increase slowly throughout the range of t, with the exception of `t < 15`, where a scale length of about `4` is evident in a blow-up of the plot.  These scale lengths, and particularly the one in `z`, indicate the needed resolution for the 2-D calculation.  Although this integration may be possible using "MethodOfLines", we choose "FEM" for its robustness.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
zz = 10; tt = 600; 
Ω = ImplicitRegion[True, { {t, 0, tt}, {z, 0, zz}}]; 
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1}];
ss = NDSolve[eq, {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, {t, z} ∈ mesh]; 
Plot3D[tair[t, z] /. ss, {t, 0, tt}, {z, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AxesLabel -> {"sec", "m", "C"}, PlotLegends -> "Tair"] 
Plot[Evaluate[{ti0[t, z], ti1[t, z], tbs[t, z], tair[t, z], tc[t, z], tgl[t, z]} /. 
  ss /. t -> tt], {z, 0, zz}, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[ {ti0, ti1, tbs, tair, tc, tgl}, Scaled[{.9, .4}]]]
```

[image]

Despite the mottled coloring, the surface is smooth, and the cusp is gone.  The curves at `t == tt` are smooth.

[image]

Note that this calculation is a memory hog, even on a 8-GB PC.  Increasing `zz` to `20` caused this PC to hang, unless `"Length" -> 1.5` is used in the computation of `mesh`.  However, doing so introduces minor irregularities in the solution.

**Addendum: Plot3D irregular coloration eliminated**

The solution described above exhibits very small amplitude, high frequency noise in `t`, which `Plot3D` evidently cannot handle.  This can be eliminated by reinterpolating the output before plotting:

```
tairs = FunctionInterpolation[tair[t, z] /. ss, {t, 0, tt}, {z, 0, zz}]
```

[image]

Incidentally, the particular parameters used here produce a solution in which `ti0` is essentially constant, and `tbs` is almost identical to `tc`.  To the extent that this holds true more generally, the computation can be simplified significantly.

**Second Addendum: Improved finite element mesh**

Michael E2 points out in a comment below that

```
Ω = FullRegion[2]; mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω, {{0, tt}, {0, zz}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 1];
```

produces a superior finite element mesh (uniform square rather than approximately uniform triangular cells).  In this case roughly half as much memory is needed, and the output does not required the reinterpolation described above.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the hint. However, by multiplying the initial conditions by f[z], I would manually manipulate the wall temperature of my air channel, which I do not want to do for the sake of the correct solution.

Comment: @Andri  I have provided a clean and robust, although slow, solution.  Note the final sentences of the Answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The new solving process is slower than the initial, however, the mesh resolution can be used to speed up the calculation with the cost of some smoothness in the solution. Also, in the most of the cases my max zz=10.

Comment: This seems to be a better discretization: `\[CapitalOmega] = FullRegion[2]; mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], {{0, tt}, {0, zz}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 1];`

Comment: @MichaelE2  Indeed, it is, using only about half as much memory and not producing the high-frequency noise.  Please write it up as an answer.  By the way, can this problem be solved by "MethodOfLines"?  Thanks.

Comment: Feel free to use it.  It's just a minor change to your code I copied.  The "MethodOfLines" gave errors about the set up (bcs/ics), and I didn't have time/inclination to investigate.